# ¿Cuando debo usar los métodos POST y GET?

Tags: php, http-post, http-get

¿Cuales son las diferencias entre los métodos `GET` y `POST`?

- ¿Es la única diferencia que se pueden ver las variables en el método `GET` en la URL y en el `POST` esta *escondido*?

¿Que (des)ventajas tiene uno al otro?

- ¿Se puede decir que las variables enviado vía `POST` están seguros?

Comment: Yo sé que POST es más seguro y debe usarse cuando vallamos a hacer modificaciones en el servidor, como delete, update, alter. Pero estoy esperando a que alguien dé una respuesta bien elaborada, pues personalmente y en lo poco que llevo en la programación, aún no le encuentro sentido a usar el método GET, mi pregunta interna sería, ¿Por qué usar GET, si post permite hacer lo mismo (o eso creo) y es más seguro?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo ¿Cómo es POST más seguro que GET? Que en el GET los parámetros sean "visibles" no implica que los valores "invisibles" del POST sean/estén más seguros.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Podrías dar alguna referencia de esa vulnerabilidad que podría presentar POST? A mí me parece en cierto grado más seguro que GET porque cualquier persona sin muchos conocimientos de programación podría enviar quizás qué cosa por el navegador. Eso no pasaría si uso POST, pero alguien que sí tenga conocimientos quizá pueda vulnerar POST y hacer el mismo daño que alguien podría hacer por GET. Por eso me urge saber si puedo tapar tal vulnerabilidad.

Comment: Los datos del POST no son invisibles en HTTP. Vale que una persona no los vea, pero pueden ser leídos por un programa de manera tan sencilla como los  datos pasados por GET. Para que fuesen más seguros deberías usar una conexión segura (HTTPS/SSL)

Answer (score 37):

**Métodos GET VS POST**

Muchas veces pensábamos erróneamente sobre la utilización de `GET` y `POST`. Tenemos a entender que cuando doy clic en una `URL` eso es `GET` y cuando envío un formulario es `POST`. Solemos pensar que enviando las peticiones por método `POST` los datos viajan seguros, por no ir como parte de la `URL` como lo hace `GET`. Este concepto es erróneo, estas no son las diferencias entre links y formularios.

Tanto el método `GET` como `POST` son protocolo `HTPP` el cual envía al servidor como petición (request) y recibe una respuesta a dicha solicitud (response).
A mi criterio, aquí está la parte de la confusión sobre los objetivos reales de ambos métodos.

[image: Petición HTTP]

**Redefinamos los conceptos**

El concepto `GET` es obtener información del servidor. Traer datos que están almacenadas en el servidor, ya sea una base de datos o archivo al cliente. Independientemente de que para eso tengamos que enviar (request) algún dato que será procesado para luego devolver la respuesta (response) que esperarnos, un ejemplo sería recibir un identificador para obtener un artículo de la base de datos.

El concepto `POST` en cambio es enviar información desde el cliente paraa que sea procesada y actualice o agregue información en el servidor, como sería la carga o actualización en si de un artículo. Cuando enviamos (request) datos a través de un formulario, estos son procesados y luego a través de una redirección, ejemplo devolvemos (response) alguna página con información.

Tanto `GET` como `POST` solicitan una respuesta del servidor y ahí donde parecen que los conceptos son iguales ya que con ambos se podría lograr los mismos objetivos. Yo podría, aunque no es correcto, enviar por `GET` ciertos datos en una `URL` u actualizar o insertar dicha información en mi base de datos, pero realmente eso le corresponde al método `POST`. De la misma manera podría solicitar una página diferente por medio de `POST` y simplemente mostrarla como respuesta, aunque eso debería ser a través de una llamada `GET`.

Las llamadas por método `GET` pueden ser `cacheadas` (historial navegador), `indexadas` por buscadores, agregar los enlaces a nuestros favoritos o hasta pasar una `URL` completa a otra persona para que ingresa a dicha página. Con el método `POST` sin embargo no se puede hacer esto.

Generalmente usamos links para ejecutar llamadas `GET` ya que la idea del link es simplemente “solicitar” una información (pagina) al `servidor` y que sea devuelta como una respuesta. Mientras usamos formularios para actualizar datos, como artículos, usuarios, etc. también en cuenta que por el método `POST` también se puede enviar más cantidad de datos que por `GET`.

> Un caso de **análisis**.

Supongamos que tengamos un carrito de compras, con una `URL` que agregue productos al carrito de compras. Generalmente si hacemos esa `URL` quedaría algo así (misitio.com/agregar_item.php?id=1). Al ser una llamada `GET`, Google podría indexar esa `URL` y podría aparecer en el buscador la palabra carrito. El problema aquí, si el visitante ejecutaría esa página automáticamente agregaría ese ítem al carrito de compras, con lo cual no es la idea ya que el visitante al buscar el carrito de compras debería simplemente entrar al sitio y no agregar ningún ítem que ni siquiera sabe cuál es. Por lo tanto, vemos que para este caso por más que usamos una `URL`, deberíamos usar una llamada al método `POST`, por ejemplo, como lo usa el `framework Symfony`, ejemplo:

```
<a onclick="f = document.createElement('form'); document.body.appendChild(f);
    f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href; f.submit();return false;"
    href="agregar_item.php?id=1">Añadir al carrito
</a>
```

Lo que hace este `URL` es muy sencillo, por medio del evento `onclick` de `JavaScript`, crea dinámicamente un formulario, le dice que será `POST` (ya que por defecto sería `GET`), le asigna la `URL` del enlace al action del form, envía el formulario y retorna false para no ejecutar el link en sí. Para hacer esto con `Symfony` simplemente usamos el helper link_to agregando la opción `post=true`:

```
<?php echo link_to('Añadir al carrito', 'agregar_item.php?id=1', 'post=true') ?>
```

Fuente donde lei el articulo:
http://blog.micayael.com/2011/02/09/metodos-get-vs-post-del-http/

Comment: Existirán casos de utilidad o de fuerza en los cuales para nuestras aplicaciones web debamos usar GET en lugar de POST?
Leo y re-leo y no le veo la razón de existir al método GET.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Los valores del GET se podrían guardar en la caché y podría ser más rápido por ello.

Answer (score 19):

Quiero visualizar/explicar en forma más practico la diferencia entre los métodos `POST`'s y `GET`'s.

Para eso vamos a usar un `<form>` y para los ejemplos usamos estos valores:

`"user" = "pepe"` | `"pass" = "cocoloco"`

Formulario con el método `GET`:

```
<form action="login.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

*Si no incluimos el atributo `method` por defecto se envia medio `GET`.*

> Con el elemento HTML Anchor `<a>` se puede enviar también (y solamente) por medio `GET`:
>
> `<a href="/libros.php?autor=pepe&libro=cocoloco">Un libro interesante</a>`

Formulario con el método `POST`:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Veamos como trata cada uno las solicitudes:

Encabezado de solicitud / *Request header* `method="get"`:

- `GET /login.php?user=pepe&pass=cocoloco&submit=Enviar HTTP/1.1`
- `Host: example.com`

Vista de la `URL`: `example.com/login.php?user=pepe&pass=cocoloco&submit=Enviar`

Encabezado de solicitud / *Request header* del `method="post"`:

- `POST /login.php HTTP/1.1`
- `Host: example.com`
- `Content-Length: 37`
- `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Vista de la `URL`: `example.com/login.php`

Por que no vemos en el `method="post"` los parámetros/valores?

Para eso hay que saber que el `HTTP Request` (solicitud HTTP) esta formado por varios componentes, nos vamos a fijar solo cuales nos interesa ahora mismo:

- [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (Dirección)
- [Request Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) (Cabecera)
- [Response Body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body) (Cuerpo)

La diferencia en el `GET` y `POST` es que el `GET` no tiene el componente `Response Body` (Cuerpo), por eso mismo incluye el `GET` los parámetros/valores en la `URI` (Dirección) y por lo tanto visible para todos.

En el caso del `POST`, sabemos ahora, que lleva el contenido del mensaje en el `Response Body` (Cuerpo).

Si nos vamos a la consola del navegador (en mi caso Chrome)

`Network` => `Name: login.php` => `Headers` => `Form Data`

podemos ver el contenido del cuerpo:

```
user=pepe&pass=cocoloco&submit=Enviar
```

El `Content-Length: 37` nos indica la longitud del contenido.

El `Content-Type` nos indica los tipos de datos que se envía.

Si quieres saber más de los distintos tipos de datos => [MIME](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions)

Ahora dirán algunos:

> *Que bien! Si uso el método `POST` no puede ver nadie la super contraseña o datos sensibles*....

*Ehm...* pues lamentablemente **NO!** (si lo mandas por `http`).

**Problema:**

Ataque del hombre en el medio...(traducido literalmente del inglés: *Man-In-the-Middle Attack*) es un ataque de Intermediario.

> Wikipedia: [Ataque de Intermediario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_intermediario)
>
> Un ataque en el que se adquiere la capacidad de leer, insertar y
>   modificar a voluntad, los mensajes entre dos partes sin que ninguna de
>   ellas conozca que el enlace entre ellos ha sido violado.

**Solución:**

Si quieres enviar tu mega super dato secreto a tu servidor tienes que usar:

[https - Protocolo seguro de transferencia de hipertexto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol_Secure)

Ahora dirán:

> Si esta cifrado puedo usar el método `GET` para enviar los datos sensibles!

*Mmmmm pues...* **nop!**

Cierto es que todo esta encriptado, pero en el caso del método `GET` las consultas se quedan guardados en los logs del servidor y entonces si sería accesible de una u otra manera.

**Conclusión corta:**

> Usa siempre `POST` para datos sensibles y `SSL HTTPS`... si quieres estar seguro y · !

**Comparaciones:**

```
               |            GET            |           POST           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Historial      | Los parámetros permanecen | Los parámetros no se     |
               | en el historial del       | guardan en el historial  |
               | navegador porque forman   | del navegador            |
               | parte de la URL           |                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Guardar en     | Es posible                | No es posible            |
Favoritos      |                           |                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Cached         | Es posible                | No es posible            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Visibilidad    | Es visible para todos -   | No se muestra en la URL  |
               | se mostrará en la barra   |                          |
               | de direcciones del        |                          |
               | navegador                 |                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Usabilidad     | No se debe utilizar para  | Utilizado para enviar    |                                               
               | enviar contraseñas u otra | contraseñas u otra       |
               | información sensible      | información sensible     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Comportamiento | Las solicitudes se        | El navegador suele       |
botón atrás /  | vuelven a ejecutar pero   | alertar al usuario de    |
reenviar       | no se puede volver a      | que los datos tendrán    |
               | enviar al servidor, si el | que volver a enviarse    |
               | HTML se almacena en el    |                          |
               | cache del navegador       |                          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Restricciones  | El límite de longitud de  | Sin restricciones        |
en la longitud | la URL suele ser de 2048  |                          |
               | caracteres, pero varía    |                          |
               | según el navegador y el   |                          |
               | servidor web              |                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Seguridad      | Es menos seguro porque    | Es más seguro ya que no  |
               | los datos enviados forman | se guarda en el          |
               | parte de la URL, por lo   | historial ni en los logs |
               | tanto, se guarda en el    | del servidor             |
               | historial del navegador y |                          |
               | en los logs del servidor  |                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Hacked         | Más fácil de hackear      | Difícil de hackear       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

aparte de las que comentas, y cada una tiene su propia *semántica* de uso. En la vida real, cada uno los maneja *mas o menos* a su antojo.

- **GET** -> Obtiene un recurso del nevagador. La dirección del recurso va en la petición (de ahí los parámetros visibles). El contenido
  **pasa** por la caché del navegador.
- **POST** -> Envía unos datos al servidor. El servidor sabrá que hacer con ellos y los procesará como sea pertinente (de ahí los parámetros
  invisibles. **NO** son parámetros, son **datos** a almacenar en un recurso). Debería emplearse para la creación de recursos nuevos, a los cuales el servidor les asignará una dirección. **No** pasan por la caché del cliente.
- **PUT** -> Envia un recurso **a una posición exacta** en el servidor. Es una especie de **GET** inverso. Parámetros visibles (como en el
  **GET**).

Answer (score 5):

Como información adicional a las otras respuestas, una diferencia importante entre GET y POST es la cantidad de datos que se pueden enviar como parámetros. Al utilizar GET existe un límite en la longitud de la URL (2000 caractéres) lo que se traduce en un límite en la cantidad/longitud de los parámetros pasados. Esta limitación no existe en el caso de POST ya que los parámetros no forman parte de la URL y por lo tanto pueden enviarse (teoricamente) una cantidad de parámetros infinitamente grande.

Comment: +1 por ser el único que menciona la limitación en el tamaño, que es una de las grandes diferencias entre los dos.

Comment: Esa información es falsa. No existe en ninguna parte del protocolo HTTP definido por RFC un límite a la longitud del URI asociado a una petición GET. Esa limitación de aproximadamente 2000 caracteres fue impuesta por IE, y actualmente es absolutamente dependiente del navegador o del servidor web que puede arrojar una respuesta 413.

Comment: @dwarandae tiene razón. Ese límite es un límite *de facto* más que una limitación en la implementación del protocolo. No obstante, no se me ocurre un caso en que sea "razonable" usar una url de ese tamaño.

Answer (score 5):

Las respuestas que hay son generalmente correctas, pero no es la definición que más me gusta, así que a pesar de que ya hay cuatro respuestas aquí va:

La diferencia básica es la **idempotencia** de GET; esto significa que el GET no tiene un efecto en los datos relacionados<sup>1</sup>. Por ejemplo, si hago una operación para obtener las películas de los cines de mi ciudad, o el resumen de una película, esta petición será mediante GET (por más peticiones que haga, eso no afectará a qué películas se están exhibiendo).

Esto permite al cliente tratar las peticiones GET con más libertad: puede cachearlas (o no) si lo desea, en caso de repetir la petición (al hacer `back` en el navegador, por ejemplo) no necesita advertir al usuario, etc.

Por el contrario, POST implica que la petición puede cambiar datos en el servidor (por ejemplo, que se reserve una entrada a mi nombre en un cine). Eso hace que haya que ser más cuidadoso con las peticiones POST, ya que hay que evitar crear peticiones si no se está seguro que es lo que el usuario quiere (el famoso mensaje de aviso al hacer `back` con el navegador).

Una forma de minimizar los problemas del POST es POST-Redirect-GET; al enviar un formulario POST no te devuelve los datos de la operación sino que te redirige a otra página; desde esa página, con un GET de un id de transacción puedes ver los resultados, por ejemplo el número de tu entrada de cine (así, puedes hacer `back` hasta el GET para recuperar los resultados sin hacer el POST de nuevo).

Por supuesto, esto es a nivel de estándar, a nivel de implementación puedes hacer un servicio GET que haga cambios en los datos del servidor, pero si luego tienes problemas cuando los usuarios lo usan será tu responsabilidad por haber roto el protocolo.

---

<sup>1</sup>A veces es algo más complicado, por ejemplo las búsquedas en Google son GET y en principio el hacer búsquedas no altera el resultado obtenido, pero también almacena las búsquedas para hacer estadísticas y hacer cambios en sugestiones, publicidad, etc.

Se seguiría considerando un GET porque lo que el usuario busca (los resultados) no se ve afectado.

Comment: No termino de comprender lo de que el GET no tiene un efecto en los datos relacionados. Dices que es a nivel estándar, ¿puedes añadir alguna referencia a ese estándar?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No es que el GET no tiene un efecto, es que **no debe tenerlo**. Si tienes una operación que cause un efecto en los datos (por ejemplo, un formulario para cambiar la descripción de una película), deberías implementarlo como POST. Una operación que no cause un efecto (consultar la descripción de una película) se puede implementar mediante GET (se podría mediante POST, pero tendría los inconvenientes arriba mencionados al navegar, etc.)

Comment: Si no lo haces así, rompes con la *semántica* (lo que significa) cada método y los clientes que se conecten a esos servicios pueden hacerlo ignorando los problemas que causan. Al fin y al cabo GET y POST no es más que un campo de cabecera de una petición HTTP, la diferencia es como son tratadas las peticiones según ese campo.

Comment: Genial. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

El método **GET** se utiliza para hacer llamadas HTTP. Se utiliza para obtener datos del servidor. Se pueden enviar parámetros al servidor en la URL de la llamada de la forma: http://tudominio.com?bar=foo&baz=foo, donde *bar* y *baz* son los parámetros y *foo* los valores en ambos casos. A nivel de mensaje HTTP solo se envía la cabecera. El cuerpo del mensaje HTTP va vacío.

El método **POST** se utiliza para enviar información al servidor. A diferencia del GET envía información del formulario que posteas en el cuerpo del mensaje HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Te daré la explicación vista desde otro enfoque

Técnicamente puedes utilizarlos indistintamente, persistir información al hacer una llamada GET o consultar información del servidor al hacer una llamada POST. a la final HTTP es un protocolo de comunicación y no de aplicación así que HTTP en si no te restringe el uso que le des.

Sin embargo el uso que le debemos dar al protocolo esta normado por una razón y es que HTTP esta hecho para poder comunicar servidores y clientes indistintamente de la plataforma (platform agnostic), en un contexto de interconexión sobre el cual se a montado toda una infraestructura tecnológica, el establecer estas normas facilita la intercomunicación entre las partes, te permite reutilizar tecnología ya existente, te facilita el uso de API's expuestas por terceros, o utilizar frameworks/librerias para poder consumir servicios de terceros o exponer los tuyos.

Los detalles técnicos del tamaño de la petición que debes enviar al servidor al usar tal o cual método no son tan relevantes, al desarrollar un backend debes pensar que estas exponiendo recursos y estos recursos serán accedidos por terceros o por tus propias aplicaciones cliente, al normar que metodos utilizar para leer información GET (navegación), crear (POST), modificar (UPDATE), eliminar (DELETE), OPTIONS, HEAD etc. estas dando mayor expresividad a tu API el utilizarla se vuelve mas natural, puedes reutilizar tecnológia existente como frameworks que te ayudan a generar código genérico para exponer tus servicios, este código generado utiliza los métodos (GET, POST y amigos) para exponer tu API. Tu puedes modificar este comportamiento ya que como te mencioné técnicamente no tienes restricciónes pero si te sales de la norma (del standard) entonces quedas a tu suerte.

Debes considerar que también esta normado los conceptos de safe e idempotencia para los diferentes métodos por ejemplo GET es safe e idempotente pero POST no es ni safe ni idempotente, si no utilizas los metodos según la norma entonces como encajarias safe e idempotencia en tu API? tendrías que definir que es safe e idempotencia en tu API, todas las librerías cliente fueron desarrolladas asumiendo todos estos conceptos y standards y si te sales de la norma como te mencione entonces quedas a tu suerte, si haces esto debes parchear tu API para que tus normas se adapten a toda la infraestructura que ya tenemos hoy en día sobre HTTP.