# ¿Cargar datos en un input desde ajax con php y mysql al cargar la pagina?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Que tal, alguien podria decirme como cargar los datos de una consulta en unas cajas de texto desde PHP con ajax al momento de cargar la pagina html que se añadan los resultados en las input.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahorita.

```
<?php
include '../conexion.php';
$query = "SELECT
  usuarios.usuario,
  usuarios.contrasenia,
  datos_personales.nombre,
  datos_personales.apellido_p,
  datos_personales.apellido_m,
  datos_personales.edad,
  datos_personales.correo,
  datos_personales.telefono,
  datos_personales.celular,
  direcciones.calle,
  direcciones.no_exterior,
  direcciones.no_interior,
  direcciones.colonia,
  direcciones.municipio,
  direcciones.estado,
  direcciones.codigo_postal
  FROM
  usuarios
  INNER JOIN datos_personales ON usuarios.id = datos_personales.usuarios_id
  INNER JOIN direcciones ON datos_personales.id = direcciones.datos_personales_id WHERE usuarios.id = '1'";

  $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

  $datos = new stdClass();

  if($resultado->num_rows > 0){

    $fila = $resultado->fetch_array();

    $datos->usuario = $fila['usuario'];
    $datos->contra = $fila['contrasenia'];
    $datos->nombre = $fila['nombre'];
    $datos->apellido_p = $fila['apellido_p'];
    $datos->apellido_m = $fila['apellido_m'];
    $datos->edad = $fila['edad'];
    $datos->correo = $fila['correo'];
    $datos->telefono = $fila['telefono'];
    $datos->celular = $fila['celular'];
    $datos->calle = $fila['calle'];
    $datos->no_exterior = $fila['no_exterior'];
    $datos->no_interior = $fila['no_interior'];
    $datos->colonia = $fila['colonia'];
    $datos->municipio = $fila['municipio'];
    $datos->estado = $fila['estado'];
    $datos->codigo_postal = $fila['codigo_postal'];

  }


  echo json_encode($datos);

  $conexion->close();

 ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'cargarDatos.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{id:$('#cambiar').val()}
  }).done(function(respuesta){
    $('#txtUsuario').val(respuesta.usuario);
    $('#txtContra').val(respuesta.contra);
    $('#txtNombre').val(respuesta.nombre);
    $('#txtApellidoP').val(respuesta.apellido_p);
    $('#txtApellidoM').val(respuesta.apellido_m);
    $('#txtEdad').val(respuesta.edad);
    $('#txtCorreo').val(respuesta.correo);
    $('#txtTelefono').val(respuesta.telefono);
    $('#txtCelular').val(respuesta.celular);
    $('#txtCalle').val(respuesta.calle);
    $('#txtNoExterior').val(respuesta.no_exterior);
    $('#txtNoInterior').val(respuesta.no_interior);
    $('#txtColonia').val(respuesta.colonia);
    $('#txtMunicipio').val(respuesta.municipio);
    $('#txtEstado').val(respuesta.estado);
    $('#txtCodigoPostal').val(respuesta.codigo_postal);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../F/jquery.min.js">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../recursos/favicon.jpg">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <form action="">
    <h2 class="head">Actualizar datos</h2>
      <div class="contenedorSesion">
        <label for="txtUsuario" class="etiquetas">Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" id="txtUsuario" value="" required>
        <label for="txtContra" class="etiquetas">Contrase&ntildea:</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtContra" id="txtContra" value="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedorDatos">
          <label for="txtNombre" class="etiquetas">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" value="" required>
         <label for="txtApellidoP" class="etiquetas">Apellido paterno:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtApellidoP" id="txtApellidoP" value="" required>
         <label for="txtApellidoM" class="etiquetas">Apellido materno:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtApellidoM" id="txtApellidoM" value="" required>
         <label for="txtEdad" class="etiquetas">Edad:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtEdad" id="txtEdad" value="" required>
         <label for="txtCorreo" class="etiquetas">Correo:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtCorreo" id="txtCorreo" value="" required>
         <label for="txtTelefono" class="etiquetas">Telefono:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtTelefono" id="txtTelefono" value="" required>
         <label for="txtCelular" class="etiquetas">Celular:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtCelular" id="txtCelular" value="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedorDireccion">
         <label for="txtCalle" class="etiquetas">Calle</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtCalle" id="txtCalle" value="" required>
         <label for="txtNoExterior" class="etiquetas">No. Exterior:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtNoExterior" id="txtNoExterior" value="" required>
         <label for="txtNoInterior" class="etiquetas">No. Interior:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtNoInterior" id="txtNoInterior" value="" required>
         <label for="txtColonia" class="etiquetas">Colonia:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtColonia" id="txtColonia" value="" required>
         <label for="txtMunicipio" class="etiquetas">Municipio:</label>
              <input type="text" name="txtMunicipio" id="txtMunicipio" value="" required>
         <label for="txtEstado" class="etiquetas">Estado:</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtEstado" id="txtEstado" value="" required>
        <label for="txtCodigoPostal" class="etiquetas">Código postal:</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtCodigoPostal" id="txtCodigoPostal" value="" required>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios" class="btn-enviar">
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas importando la librería JQuery despues de tu archivo Javascript, por lo que todas funcionalidades comunes de DOM, eventos, efectos y AJAX de esta todavia no están definidos al momento de querer utilizarlas provocando que el código se rompa y no se ejecute. Deberías importar primero la librería y después tu archivo Javascript.

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Estas haciendo la petición `AJAX` mediante el método `POST`. Deberías utilizar el método `GET` para obtener información del servidor.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'cargarDatos.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { id : $('#cambiar').val() }
})
```

---

**Notas ***

Estas importando un script de Javascript como si se tratase de una archivo CSS, deberías eliminar esta línea de tu código:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../F/jquery.min.js">
```

Si queres crear un objeto con el resultado de la consulta, la mejor alternativa es utilizar `mysqli_fetch_object()` en vez de traer el resultado como arreglo y crear el objeto manualmente asignado el valor a la clave correspondiente. *Importante: las claves van a tener el mismo nombre que las columnas de la tabla.*

```
if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado);
}
```

* *No es obligatorio realizar estos cambios ya que no contribuyen a resolver el problema pero mejoran el código existente.*

Comment: La petición `AJAX` recibe información del servidor independientemente de si esta es de tipo `POST` o `GET`, estos dos últimos son la forma en como se envía la información al servidor. `GET` es mediante la URL `cargarDatos.php?dato1=xx&dato2=xx` y `POST` se envían desde el cuerpo de la petición `HTTP`.

Comment: @Lixus Es verdad, pero `GET` se debería utilizar para obtener información del servidor y `POST` para enviar información al servidor para que se procese. [Referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get)

Comment: Ambos mandan información y reciben información del servidor, no estás entendiendo bien la diferencia de ambos.