# ¿Por qué los formularios tienen el método get?

Tags: html, formularios, get, http-get

En HTML, los formularios contienen controles interactivos que se utilizan para enviar información al servidor web. Esos formularios pueden tener dos métodos diferentes (get y post) que se corresponden con los verbos HTTP GET y POST respectivamente.

El verbo GET se usa para recibir información mientras que el verbo POST se usa para enviar información. Entonces, si los formularios son para enviar información y el verbo GET es para recuperar información. ¿Por qué existe el método GET en los formularios web?

Comprendo que una diferencia es que con GET los datos se envían a través de la URI, mientras que con POST los datos se envían como parte del cuerpo (*body*) del formulario. Pero al final, el formulario está haciendo lo mismo: enviar datos.

Comment: Hola @Alvaro Montoro,  No se si habras visto ya [este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get) de la comunidad, espero ayudarte, y que cambien las tornas por una vez.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso No me había fijado en ese artículo. Aunque no exactamente igual, mi pregunta es muy parecida a esa, quizás debería marcarla como duplicada.

Comment: Creo que son preguntas diferentes, pero que las respuestas aplican a este caso. Así como están parecen duplicadas (a menos que elabores en qué se diferenciarían)... Lo que no entiendo es por qué la marcaron como de baja calidad :-\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo diría que los verbos HTTP especifican que hacer con los recursos a los que se refiere la URL en cuestión.

Un formulario web es simplemente un metodo de entrada para que el usuario especifique la información requerida para armar una solicitud.

Así, un formulario que usa el metodo GET solo está solicitando un recurso, no lo modifica, por lo que la solicitud puede cachearse o repetirse (es idempotente).

Mientras que un formulario con método POST puede modificar el recurso y no debe cachearse ni repetirse.

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero que sería preciso entender es lo que ocurre cuando pulsamos el botón **`ENVIAR`** de cualquier formulario: una comunicación cliente/servidor basada en el protocolo `HTTP`. Es decir, un cliente (generalmente un navegador web) envía una solicitud a un servidor (la mayoría de las veces un servidor web como Apache, Nginx, IIS, Tomcat, etc.), usando el protocolo HTTP. El servidor responde la solicitud utilizando el mismo protocolo.

Un esquema básico de la arquitectura cliente / servidor se puede representar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, en toda comunicación mediante el protocolo `HTTP` *no hay ida sin vuelta*. Cuando tu envías algo mediante el método `GET`, o `POST` o cualquier otro, **estás enviando y recibiendo información**.

**¿Por qué existe el método `GET` en los formularios web?**

En los formularios web el método `GET` existe **por definición**. Es más, **es el método por defecto** como indica la W3C Recommendation en el apartado [*17.3 The `FORM` element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method):

> ```
> method = get|post [CI]
> ```
>
> This attribute specifies which HTTP method will be used to submit the
>   form data set. Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the
>   default) and "post". See the section on form submission for usage
>   information.
>
> ---
>
> Este atributo especifica qué método HTTP se usará para enviar el
>   [conjunto de datos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set) del formulario. Los **valores posibles** (sin distinción
>   de mayúsculas y minúsculas) son **"`get`" (predeterminado)** y "post".
>   Consulte la sección sobre [envío de formularios](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format) para obtener
>   información de uso.

Y existe porque es una forma válida definida por el protocolo `HTTP/1.1`, utilizado en el envío de datos al servidor a través de formularios. Es lo que indica el [apartado 9.3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616bis/draft-lafon-rfc2616bis-03.txt) de dicho protocolo :

> El método `GET` significa recuperar cualquier información (en forma de
>   entidad) que se identifica mediante Request-URI. Si el URI de
>   solicitud se refiere a un proceso de producción de datos, son los
>   datos producidos los que serán  **devueltos** como entidad en la
>   respuesta y no el texto fuente del proceso, a menos que ese texto sea
>   el resultado del proceso.

En el apartado [*17.13.3 Processing form data*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set) de la W3C Recommendation viene indicado cómo el servidor actuará cuando recibe un formulario con el método `GET`:

> Si el método es "`get`" y la acción es un URI HTTP, el agente de
>   usuario toma el valor de la acción, agrega un ? ' a él, luego agrega
>   el conjunto de datos del formulario codificado utilizando el tipo de
>   contenido "`application / x-www-form-urlencoded`". El agente de
>   usuario luego cruza el enlace a este URI. En este escenario, los datos
>   del formulario están restringidos a códigos ASCII.

En pocas palabras, `GET` no es un *verbo*, es un método bien definido para establecer comunicaciones con el servidor, un método como cualquier otro... `OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT`.

Cuando usamos cualquiera de ellos, estamos estableciendo una comunicación cliente/servidor. Enviamos algo y le decimos al servidor que trate ese algo como está especificado. Así de sencillo.

Todo lo demás es como dices en la pregunta.

Cuando se usa el método `GET` enviamos una petición sin cuerpo al servidor, pues todo va en la URL:

> El método GET es el método utilizado por el navegador para solicitar
>   al servidor que envíe de vuelta un recurso determinado: "Hola,
>   servidor, quiero obtener este recurso". En este caso, el navegador
>   envía un cuerpo vacío. Como el cuerpo está vacío, si se envía un
>   formulario con este método, los datos enviados al servidor se anexan a
>   la URL.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)</sub>

Por lo tanto una petición `GET` se muestra así:

```
GET /?say=Hi&to=Mom HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
```

Cuando usamos el método `POST`, los datos se envían al servidor con un cuerpo:

> El método POST es un poco diferente. Es el método que utiliza el
>   navegador para comunicarse con el servidor cuando solicita una
>   respuesta que tenga en cuenta los datos proporcionados en el cuerpo de
>   la solicitud HTTP: "Hola, servidor, eche un vistazo a estos datos y
>   envíeme un resultado apropiado". Si se envía un formulario utilizando
>   este método, los datos se anexan al cuerpo de la solicitud HTTP.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)</sub>

Una petición con `POST` se presenta entonces así:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13

say=Hi&to=Mom
```

El encabezado `Content-Length` indica el tamaño del cuerpo y el encabezado `Content-Type` indica el tipo de recurso enviado al servidor.

Comment: @ACedano me encanto tu explicacion, muy bien resumida y explicada.