# Error en el servidor remoto: (414) Request-URI Too Long. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, windows-forms, webservice

```
private void Send()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT 
                cod,
                Format(fecha, 'Short Date') as fecha,
                Format(hora, 'Short Time') as hora,
                Num,
                1 as Tipo
            FROM Control";

    OleDbDataAdapter d = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    d.Fill(ds);
    var n = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);

    string Json = n.ToString();

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:36862/Services/Control.svc/Control/"+ Json);
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();     ///ERRO ME SALE AQUI
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

***Me sale este error***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***SERVICIO: Aqui es donde estoy esperando***

```
namespace Registro.Services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IColegio
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Control/{Json}",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Control> GetControl(string Json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que no lo haces con un Post?

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get. A lo cual añado que el tamaño de las peticiones GET es mucho más limitado que el tamaño de las peticiones POST.