# ¿Cómo evitar que vean los datos que generan de la consulta en la URL?

Tags: php, mysql, url

les planteo mi duda o problema.(SOLUCIONADO) GRACIAS A TODOS!
Estoy haciendo un sistema en PHP y estoy aplicando medidas de seguridad, resulta que hace todo bien. El problema inicia cuando le doy clic a un boton que me redirecciona a la otra pagina y en la URL me salen los dos parametros.
Es decir:

```
localhost/M/E/califalumno.php?cod=estudiante1&periodo=1
```

Cuando yo cambio los valores de esta parte:

```
califalumno.php?cod=estudiante1&periodo=1
```

cuando reemplazo estudiante1 y reemplazo periodo1 por estudiante2 y periodo2 , los datos correspondientes a esos, se muestran y asi cualquier persona podria ver los datos del estudiante 2. Como pudiera solventar eso? Podrian ayudarme? Muchas gracias de antemano!
Para evitar eso pienso que la solucion seria que me arrojara la url de la siguiente manera:

```
localhost/M/E/califalumno.php
```

El codigo que realiza la consulta es la siguiente:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once "M/php_conexion.php";
include_once "M/class_buscar.php";
include_once "M/funciones.php";
if($_SESSION['tipo_user']=='n' or $_SESSION['tipo_user']=='v' or $_SESSION['tipo_user']=='r'){ 
    $alumno=limpiar($_SESSION['cod_user']);
    $oAlumno=new Consultar_Alumno($alumno);
    $nombre_alumno=$oAlumno->consultar('nombre').' '.$oAlumno->consultar('apellido');
$mecodigo=limpiar($_SESSION['cod_user']);
$oMecodigo=new Consultar_Alumno($mecodigo);
$nombre_codigo=$oMecodigo->consultar('doc');
}else{
    header('Location:error.php');
}?><?php include_once "menu/m_alumno.php"; ?>
    <h2><?php echo $nombre_alumno;?></h2>
          <?php 
                $pa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE doc='$nombre_codigo' order by nombre");                
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
                    $url=$row['doc'];
        $url2='periodo=1';
             ?> 
                    <div align="center">
                        <a href="M/E/califalumno.php?cod=<?php echo $url; ?>&<?php echo $url2; ?>" title="VER MIS CALIFICACIONES" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
                            <strong><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="font-size:20px;color:white"></i> <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row['apellido']; ?> <BR>VER CALIFICACIONES</strong>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hay un login previo del usuario? Sería lógico que hubiera un login de usuario a partir del cual crees una cookie o variables de sesión y que antes de mostrar la calificación compruebes que dicha calificación pertenece al alumno logado o a un supervisor que pueda verlo si esa figura existe en tu lógica. Además puedes enviar las variables por post mediante un formulario en lugar de por enlace.

Comment: Si existe un login de usuario y es lo que no logro por que al cambiar el ID y el numero de periodo me muestra los datos del alumno asignado con la ID. Puedo enviar el enlace como un post? Gracias por responder! :)

Comment: te he puesto una respuesta con ambas cosas, no son excluyentes, pero al menos deberías hacer el envío por post, aunque lo ideal sería que también comprobaras que el usuario está autorizado antes de mostrar los datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comprobar usuario autorizado en `califalumno.php`: supongamos que tenemos el código único del usuario en la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['cod_user']` y que el código que envías para la consulta es este código de usuario (sino es el caso puedes crear una nueva variable que permita hacer la comparación).

```
if ($_SESSION["cod_user"] == $_REQUEST["cod"]) {
   //muestras la calificación - usuario autorizado 
} else {
   echo "Lo sentimos, no tienes permiso para acceder a esta calificación";
}
```

Enviar los datos por post a `califalumno.php`.

```
    <div align="center">
      <form action="M/E/califalumno.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cod" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="periodo" value="<?php echo $periodo_value; ?>" />
        <strong><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="font-size:20px;color:white"></i> <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></strong>
        <input type="submit" value="VER MIS CALIFICACIONES" name="btn_enviar"/>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Respuesta Correcta: Muchisimas Gracias! Me ha iluminado con su enorme aporte, le agradezco el tiempo que empeñó para ayudarme! Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El método GET en las peticiones http siempre enviará los parámetros en la URL.
Te sugiero que para el envío de parámetros que deben estar seguros, uses el método POST.

El método POST envía los datos en el cuerpo de la petición y no en la URL.

[POST](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_transferencia_de_hipertexto#POST)

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos tipos de peticiones de en una pagina web POST y GET , estos métodos normalmente se explican a la hora de crear un formulario en el que decides como mandas la información.

- **GET:** Los datos son transmitidos en la ULR, son visibles y tiene un limite de caracteres permitidos(*Sobre los 2000 dependiendo del navegador*). Al acceder a una url por defecto se esta haciendo una peticion GET.
- **POST:**  Los parámetros estan encriptados en la url, no se pueden ver a simple vista o simularlos en una url de forma manual y el limite es mucho mas alto. Es el método utilizado a la hora de mandar datos sensibles como códigos,contraseñas,etc.

[Post con las direcencias de cada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get)

**SOLUCION:** 
Hay varias formas de realizar lo que estas pidiendo:

- Tal y como te han indicado en algún comentario puedes crear un formulario  oculto en el que tengas inputs escondidos con los valores y hacer un POST
   ( *A simple vista no se vera nada y tampoco en la URL, sin embargo al abrir las herramientas de desarollador si que se podrán ver y modificar de la misma manera que la url y acceder a otros alumnos* )
- Por lo que he visto el usuario inicia sesión, por lo tanto mi recomendación es aprovechar esto de la siguiente forma. La sesión eres tu el que la inicia con los datos del alumno por lo tanto no te la pueden falsificar. Aprovechando esto simplemente haz lo siguiente:

  ```
   if(!isset($_SESSION["cod_user"])){
      // Si la sesion no esta iniciada, redirecionalo al login
      header("location:../login/");
      die();
   }
   // Si el usuario esta logueado, obten sus resultados y escribelos
   mostrarCalificaciones($_SESSION["cod_user"]);
  ```

Haciendo esto simplemente cuando el usuario este loguado mandalo a la pgina que contenga esto y tendra sus calificaciones y si no esta logueado no las podra ver, pero en ningun caso podra acceder a otras.

Comment: Problema solucionado, gracias por su ayuda!!