# Acceder al resultado de un método dentro de una clase por medio de $.get() en JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, function, get, class

Tengo dentro de la url "usuarios.cls.php" la clase Usuarios, y dentro de ésta tengo una function que me retorna una lista de los deseos que guarda un usuario en la BD, y necesito por medio del método $.get() de JQuery, necesito acceder a esa función para capturar el resultado que me arroja, algo así como:

PHP:

```
class Usuario{

    public function retornarResultados(){

         return response;

    }

}
```

Y por medio del Javascript, acceder al resultado de esa funcion retornarResultados() por medio del método $.get(), algo como..:

```
$.get("usuarios.cls.php", ... )
```

Comment: Estás usando algún framework de PHP? No podes correr directamente un método de PHP desde Javascript. Tenés que hacer una llamada a un archivo PHP y que ese archivo se ocupe de correr el método y de devolver el resultado.

Comment: Gracias @azeós por darme sugerencias...
No estoy usando ningún framework de PHP, es totalmente nativo.
Pensé hacerlo con ajax, pero creí que con el $.get() se podía

Answer (score 0):

No lo probé, pero lo lógica sería algo así:

**getUsuarios.php**:

```
<?php

include 'usuarios.cls.php';
$usuario = new Usuario();

return $usuario->retornarResultados();
```

```
$.get('getUsuarios.php', function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Gracias azeós por la colaboración.
Lamentablemente, no me retorna ningún resultado en la consola, lo probé con el método $.get() dentro de un $(document).ready(function(){}), para imprimir el resultado de una vez, pero no me salen nada aún... conoces alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: aprovecho para hacerte una pregunta y salirme de una enorme duda, cuál es la diferencia entre $.pos() y $.get()?

Comment: @Candelo fijate en la solapa de "red/network" de las herramientas de desarrollador (no se si usas Firefox o Chrome), que aparece cuando se ejecuta el `GET`. Por ahí está mal el path del archivo PHP y por eso no se ejecuta nada. [POST y GET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get)

Comment: Me sale el error 404, Not Found

Comment: @Candelo entonces el path del archivo está mal. En vez de poner `getUsuarios.php` escribí la ruta completa al archivo: `$.get('http://tuweb.com/getUsuarios.php')`.

Comment: Ahora sí me imprimió algo en la consola, pero es un error :( ...
Creo que sí debe de ser el path, pero tengo la ruta bien copiada en el js..:
Mira el error:

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(ajax/usuarios.ajax.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php</b> on line 3
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening 'ajax/usuarios.ajax.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php on line 3

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'AjaxUsuarios' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php on line <b>5

Comment: Está mal la ruta del `include`. Si `getPrueba.php` y `usuarios.ajax.php` están en la misma carpeta, no agregues `ajax/` como parte del path del `include`.

Comment: Eliminé ya el ajax/ porque tenía los dos archivos en la misma carpeta, lo estoy haciendo bajo el patrón MVC, y sin embargo, no me imprime el return que tengo dentro de la función de la clase Usuarios, me sale el siguiente error en conso:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function AjaxUsuarios() in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\ajax\getPrueba.php on line 5

Comment: Lo intenté hasta con require, y require_once, pero no me funcionó, ésto es lo que tengo en getUsuario.php...:
<?php 

include "usuarios.ajax.php";

$usua = Usuarios();
return $usua->retornarcoso();

Comment: En la clase Usuario tengo lo siguiente:
class AjaxUsuarios{

      public function retornarcoso(){
        return "w";
    }

}

Comment: Y como los dos archivos, tango el archivo de la clase Usuario() que se llama usuarios.ajax.php lo tengo dentro de la misma carpeta como el de getUsuarios, entonces lo quité del include, e hice el sgte js:

Comment: $.get("ajax/getPrueba.php", function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
Pero no tengo idea de porque me sale ese error

Comment: @Candelo por favor actualizá tu pregunta incluyendo el contenido de todos los archivos que estás mencionando, sus rutas y los errores. Así te podemos ayudar mejor.