# Si el método GET y POST son globales porque no puedo leer las variables que están almacenadas dentro?

Tags: php, post, get

sucede que tengo 2 paginas .php en la una eh escrito el siguiente codigo. En donde defino una varible dentro de la matriz GET.

```html
<?php 
     $_GET["Nombre"]="Juanes"; 
?>
```

Y en la otra pagina eh escrito el siguiente código, en donde busco leer esa misma variable definida anteriormente en GET.

```html
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["Nombre"]))
    echo 'Tu nombre es: '.$_GET["Nombre"];
 ?>
```

Soy nuevo en este lenguaje y tengo entendido que tanto el método POST y GET se consideran globales, pero al tratar de leer la variable en el segundo archivo no me funciona y no entiendo el porque ? digo si al estar esa varible definida en el servidor(en forma global) debería poder leerlo en el segundo archivo. También entiendo que para que funcione debería hacer una referencia hacia el otro archivo con un **action="otraPagina.php"** y cuando hago esta referencia si me funciona osea si puedo leer en el otro archivo. No comprendo por que no me funciona con la primera forma, a la final se están creando las variables dentro del mismo servidor y debería poder leer la variable, de antemano muchas gracias :3

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, pasa que tenia entendido que al tener una variable definida en el servidor cualquier otro archivo ya podría acceder a la misma.

Comment: `$_GET` y `$_POST` son globales en un contexto bien definido: cuando envías datos al servidor por medio de un formulario o por medio de una URL. Aquí el concepto *global* no significa disponible en cualquier parte. Significa disponible únicamente en el script al que son enviados los datos. Lo que sí estaría disponible en todo el contexto del servidor serían las [variables de `$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.session.php), mientras ésta se mantenga activa.

Answer (score 2):

Veo que andas un poco confuso. Existen varias formas en **PHP** para obtener datos desde pagina 1 y trabajar con ellos en la página 2 o incluso en cualquier página si usarías por ejemplo la función [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) de **PHP**.

**Veamos primero lo que nos dice el manual de `$_GET` y el ambito de las variables**

> Es un array asociativo de variables pasado al script actual vía
> parámetros URL (también conocida como cadena de consulta). Tenga en
> cuenta que el array no solo se rellena para las solicitudes GET, sino
> para todas las solicitudes con una cadena de consulta.

> $HTTP_GET_VARS contiene la misma información, pero no es una
> superglobal. (Note que $HTTP_GET_VARS y $_GET son diferentes
> variables y que PHP los usa de forma diferente)

*Ahora veamos tu duda sobre que es una superglobal variable, y el ámbito de las variables.*

> Nota: esta es una 'superglobal' o una variable automatic global. Significa simplemente que es una variable que está disponible en cualquier parte del script. No hace falta hacer global $variable; para acceder a la misma desde funciones o métodos.

Con esto no quieren decir que dicha variable esté disponible en cualquier parte de tu entorno de desarrollo, sino cuando trabajas con funciones o métodos normalmente si existen un variable fuera de su entorno uno debería declarar el entorno de dicha variable para poder trabajar con él, veamos algún ejemplo:

```
$nombre = 'Juan'; /* ámbito global */

function nombre() {
  // Retornar valor
  echo $nombre; /* referencia a una variable del ámbito local */
}
nombre();
```

Este script no producirá salida, ya que la sentencia echo utiliza una versión local de la variable `$nombre`, a la que no se ha asignado ningún valor en su ámbito.

PHP tiene reservada la palabra clave global para asignar su ámbito.

```
$nombre = 'Juan'; /* ámbito global */
// Supongamos que obtenemos a Luis mediante $_POST['nom'];

function nombre() {
  // Para poder trabajar con $nombre debes usar 'global'      
  global $nombre;
  // Retornar valor
  echo "$nombre y";

  // Las superglobales están disponibles en cualquier ámbito y no
  // requieren 'global'. Las superglobales están disponibles desde
  // PHP 4.1.0, y ahora HTTP_POST_VARS se considera obsoleta.
  echo $_POST['nom'];
  
}
nombre();
```

El script anterior producirá la salida **Juan y Luis**. Al declarar `$nombre` globalmente dentro de la función, todas las referencias a tales variables se referirán a la versión global. No hay límite al número de variables globales que se pueden manipular dentro de una función.

Manual PHP: [Ambito de las variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Veamos como podrías pasar datos con GET y POST.

Para usar el método `GET` o bien creas un formulario HTML con sus datos que quieras pasar u otra alternativa es usando una url, para ello debes crear algo como `tu-enlace.php?nombre=$tuvariable` donde `nombre` es el identificador de tu `GET`, es decir, para obtener dicho parámetro en la página que has vinculado haces esto `$_GET["nombre"]`.

**EJEMPLO**

**Pagina 1**

```
// Variable
$nombre = "Juanes"; 
// Pasamos nuestra variable usando el metodo GET en nuestra URL. 
<a href="pagina2.php?nombre=<?php echo $nombre; ?>">Abrir pagina 2</a>
```

**pagina 2**

```
// Obtener nuestro parametro por el metodo GET
//
// Si esta definido tu variable GET
if (isset($_GET["nombre"])) {
   // Obtenemos datos
   $nombre = $_GET["nombre"] ?: ''; 
   echo $nombre;
}
```

Veamos un ejemplo por `POST`, para ello usamos un formulario, para obtener tus parámetros debes usar el identificador `name="identificador"`.

También podrías usar `method="GET"`, y en página dos envede usar `$_POST` debes usar `$_GET`.

**EJEMPLO**

**Pagina 1**

```
// Variable
<?php $nombre = "Juanes"; ?>

<form method="POST" action="pagina2.php">
   <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**pagina 2**

```
// Obtener nuestro parametro por el metodo POST
//
// Si esta definido nuestro formulario
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
   // Obtenemos datos
   $nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?: ''; 
   echo $nombre;
}

// Si quieres usar el methodo GET cambia $_POST por $_GET y tambien debes 
// cambiar en tu formulario el metodo a usar.
```

Te dejo más información sobre el método GET y POST y que viene muy bien entender sus diferencias
[Respuesta SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34904/cuando-debo-usar-los-m%C3%A9todos-post-y-get/34925#34925)

Answer (score 0):

El problema no está en definir la superglobal con GET, POST o REQUEST; si no en cómo se transmite la información de un archivo al otro por cada uno de esos métodos.

POST envía la información al otro archivo por medio del [método POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) mientras que GET la envía por la URL.

Supongamos que tienes un archivo:

**file1.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['a'] + $_GET['b'];
```

Ahora desde el navegador mandas a llamar esa URL con un par de parámetros:

```
http://ruta_de_tu_servidor/file1.php?a=3&b=5
```

Se imprimirá: `8`

El mismo resultado si accedes a esa página, desde otra, ya sea por `<form>` o por link:

```
<a href="file1.php?a=3&b=5">Calcular suma de 3 y 5</a>
```

Si llamaras la URL sin los parámetros dará un error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: a in ...\file1.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: b in ...\file1.php on line 2
```

Desde PHP puro no hay manera de asignar POST o GET manualmente y enviarlos a otro archivo sin usar los métodos correctamente porque al acceder al nuevo archivo las variables serán descargadas de la memoria inmediatamente. Entonces, para usar los métodos correctamente, debe ser:

POST: Formulario HTML
GET: Formulario HTML, Link con parámetros, Escribiendo la URL con parámetros.
Javascript: Esto no es PHP, pero desde acá si se puede setear directamente POST.

Si necesitas usar superglobales para enviar información de un archivo a otro, usar correctamente los métodos GET o POST. O bien usar [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)