# ¿Cómo pasar una variable a otro archivo PHP?

Tags: php

Quiero pasar una llamada `$usuario` que está en mi archivo *login.php* a *index.php* y no puedo hacerlo por métodos, entonces lo que hice fue hacer un `include` desde el archivo *index.php* a *login.php*, pero me sale este error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "usuario" in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\login\login.php on line 7

Warning: Undefined array key "contraseña" in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\login\login.php on line 8

Warning: Undefined array key "btnlogin" in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\login\login.php on line 12
```

Comment: Te aconsejo que hagas un recorrido del sitio y miras como preguntar. Lo suyo sería que compartieras el código completo, para que te puedan ayudar. Para trabajar con variables en diferentes páginas, podrias usar una SESSION, te dejo una respuesta que quizás te pueda orientar por el método GET: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446850/si-el-m%c3%a9todo-get-y-post-son-globales-porque-no-puedo-leer-las-variables-que-est%c3%a1/446863#446863

Comment: Haz `var_dump`  del / los objeto(s) que intentas usar en las líneas 7, 8 y 12 y que están levantado estos Warning. Se trata de un problema básico de depuración. Si aprendes a depurar tu código ahorrarás muchísimo tiempo.